# Erro Junit Eclipse: "No test found with test runner JUnit 5"

Tags: java, eclipse, testes, testes-de-unidade, junit

Não estou conseguindo rodar meus testes no Eclipse, segue abaixo um simples teste que não funciona:

```
import org.junit.Assert;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.BeforeEach;
import org.junit.jupiter.api.Test;

class TesteTest {

    @BeforeEach
    void setUp() throws Exception {
    }

    @Test
    void test() {
       Assert.assertTrue(true);
   }

}
```

Mensagem de Erro: **No test found with test runner JUnit 5**

Run Configurations:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Source:
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Libs:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: o que vc quer testar basicamente? Não tem nenhuma Classe?

Comment: Nesse pedaço de código não estou testando nenhuma classe, esse exemplo é apenas para testar o JUnit, qualquer teste que faço recebo essa mesma mensagem de erro!

Comment: Se não fizer questão de utilizar o JUnit 5, ali no campo "Test runner" seleciona "Junit 4".

Comment: There's new way on how to configure your test with JUnit 5 explained on https://www.eclipse.org/community/eclipse_newsletter/2017/october/article5.php

Answer (score 0):

se estiver tentando com jUnit 5 coloca @RunWith(JUnitPlatform.class)

importa org.junit.platform.runner.JUnitPlatform; porque assim o eclipse reconhece as classes de teste do jUnit como classes de teste

Comment: Coloquei a anotação na classe mas o erro continua, tem alguma coisa além disso para fazer?

Comment: @PedroHenrique qual versão do java e do eclipse você está usando

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java Developers. Version: 2018-12 (4.10.0) e Java 8 (1.8)

Comment: @PedroHenrique putz, creio que você caiu no bug https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/show_bug.cgi?id=537470, da uma olhadinha e veja se é isso mesmo

Answer (score 0):

1- Verifique se vc tem a dependência do JUnit no classpath do seu projeto. Isso geralmente é declarado no pom.xml (maven) ou build.gradle (gradle)

1.1 Caso seja um projeto gradle, essa instrução já resolveu meu problema antes:

```
dependencies {
  testImplementation 'junit:junit:<x.y>'
}

test {
  useJUnit()
```

}

1.2 Caso seja maven, tem alguns guias pra configuração, [tipo esse](https://maven.apache.org/surefire/maven-surefire-plugin/examples/junit-platform.html)